# Meteor - registerHelper, can't access user value

Tags: meteor, helper

I am using meteor to build a website similar to reddit. I used the `account-ui` package for user accounts, but I had trouble getting the user value. I was able to create an account and login, but when I post a comment, it shows that I am an anonymous user. Here's the code -

```
Template.registerHelper('getUser', function(user_id) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user_id});
    if (user) {
        return user.username;
    }
    else {
        return "anon";
    }
});
```

post a comment -

```
Template.comment_form.events({
    "submit .js-save-comment-form":function(event){
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            // here is an example of how to get the comment out of the form:
            var comment = event.target.comment.value;
            console.log("The comment is: "+comment);

            Comments.insert({
                website: Router.current().params._id, 
                comment: comment, 
                createdOn: new Date(),
                user: Meteor.user()._id
            });
            event.target.comment.value = "";
        }
        else {
            alert('You need to be logged in to submit comments!');
        }

        return false; // stop the form submit from reloading the page

    }
});
```

I was logged in as user test, but when I posted a comment, it shows it's posted by anon, which means the server didn't return the user value

[image]

Comment: Did you publish & subscribe?

Comment: Are you sure that you publish the `username` field and the relevant user details? Please share the relevant template and helper code and make sure that the input is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

See if this makes the usernames show up.  It's not the production solution, but it should give you some idea what's going on if it works.

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  if (!this.userId) return null;
  return Meteor.users.find({},{fields: {'username': 1, '_id': 1}});
});
```